# No puedo validar un condicional de un método de una clase

Tags: java, clase, interfaz-gráfica

estoy trabajando con una GUI de un ATM. Mi problema tiene que ver cuando quiero validar mi Clave de usuario y NIP. Tengo una clase llamada BaseDatosBanco donde tengo un método para validar si la clave de usuario existe y si el NIP coincide. Los valores los obtengo mediante un jtextfield donde el usuario ingresar su clave y NIP. Tengo un botón donde al hacer click entra en un condicional con mi jlabel donde compara el texto. Primera compara si pide la clave de usuario y luego el NIP. Al final llamo a mi metodo autenticarUsuario para validar la clave y NIP ingresado, si los valores coincide me lleva a una nueva interfaz donde esta mi menu. El problema es que siempre me regresa que los valores ingresados por el usuario no coincide con mi arreglo de objeto Cuenta donde están los valores de las cuentas.

Puede que sea un error de lógica de mi parte, y en tal caso me podrían orientar en otra forma de hacerlo?

========================================================================
Clase BaseDatosBanco. Les adjunto los métodos relevantes.

```
public class BaseDatosBanco
{
   public static Cuenta cuentas[]; // arreglo de objetos Cuenta
   // el constructor sin argumentos de BaseDatosBanco inicializa a cuentas
   public  BaseDatosBanco()
   {
      cuentas = new Cuenta[ 2 ]; // sólo 2 cuentas para probar
      cuentas[ 0 ] = new Cuenta(12345, 54321, 1000.0, 1200.0);
      cuentas[ 1 ] = new Cuenta(98765, 56789, 200.0, 200.0 );  
   } // fin del constructor sin argumentos de BaseDatosBanco

   
   // obtiene el objeto Cuenta que contiene el número de cuenta especificado
   private Cuenta obtenerCuenta( int numeroCuenta ){
      // itera a través de cuentas, buscando el número de cuenta que coincida
      for ( Cuenta cuentaActual : cuentas ){
         // devuelve la cuenta actual si encuentra una coincidencia
         if ( cuentaActual.obtenerNumeroCuenta() == numeroCuenta )
            return cuentaActual;
      } // fin de for
      return null; // si no se enontró una cuenta que coincida, devuelve null
   } // fin del método obtenerCuenta

   
   // determina si el número de cuenta y el NIP especificados por el usuario coinciden
   // con los de una cuenta en la base de datos
   public boolean autenticarUsuario( int numeroCuentaUsuario, int nipUsuario ){
      // trata de obtener la cuenta con el número de cuenta
      Cuenta cuentaUsuario = obtenerCuenta( numeroCuentaUsuario );
      // si la cuenta existe, devuelve el resultado del método validarNIP de Cuenta
      if ( cuentaUsuario != null )
         return cuentaUsuario.validarNIP( nipUsuario );
      else
         return false; // no se encontró el número de cuenta, por lo que devuelve false
   } // fin del método autenticarUsuario
```

Interfaz_Cuenta

```
public class INTERFAZ_CUENTA extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static int cuenta;
    BaseDatosBanco datos = new  BaseDatosBanco();
    public static int NIP;
    
    /**
     * Creates new form INTERFAZ_CLAVE
     */
    public INTERFAZ_CUENTA() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        txt_numCuenta.requestFocus();
    }
```

Le adjunto el código de mi botón que hace la validación

```
  private void btn_ConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
            // TODO add your handling code here:    
           if(jLabel5.getText().equals("INGRESA EL NUMERO DE CUENTA:")){
               cuenta = Integer.parseInt(txt_numCuenta.getText()); 
               jLabel5.setText("INGRESA TU NIP:");
               txt_numCuenta.setText("");

           }else if(jLabel5.getText().equals("INGRESA TU NIP:")){
               NIP = Integer.parseInt(txt_numCuenta.getText()); 
               if(datos.autenticarUsuario(cuenta, NIP)){
               INTERFAZ_MENU menu = new INTERFAZ_MENU();
               menu.setVisible(true);
               this.setVisible(false);
           } else {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numero de cuenta o NIP invalido, intenta nuevamente");
               txt_numCuenta.setText("");
               jLabel5.setText("INGRESA EL NUMERO DE CUENTA:");           
           }
           }
            
        }
```

A recomendación del comentario de Diego les adjunto me clase Cuenta, aunque no creo que el error sea por esta clase. Tengo otros métodos en esta clase pero no tienen relevancia con lo que quiero hacer.

```
public class Cuenta 
{
   public static int numeroCuenta; // número de cuenta
   public static int nip; // NIP para autenticación
   public static double saldoDisponible; // fondos disponibles para retirar
   public static double saldoTotal; // fondos disponibles + depósitos pendientes

   // el constructor de Cuenta inicializa los atributos
   public Cuenta( int elNumeroDeCuenta, int elNIP, 
      double elSaldoDisponible, double elSaldoTotal ){
      numeroCuenta = elNumeroDeCuenta;
      nip = elNIP;
      saldoDisponible = elSaldoDisponible;
      saldoTotal = elSaldoTotal;
           
   } // fin del constructor de Cuenta

public boolean validarNIP( int nipUsuario ){
      if ( nipUsuario == nip )
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   } // fin del método validarNIP

   // devuelve el número de cuenta
   public int obtenerNumeroCuenta(){
      return numeroCuenta;  
   } // fin del método obtenerNumeroCuenta
} // fin de la clase Cuenta
```

Comment: Pon tu clase Cuenta, se supone que .obtenerNumeroCuenta() devuelve el # de cuenta, pero si te haz chispoteado pues va devolver otra cosa.
Pero lo más recomendable, es que hagas un debug hermano, con un debug ya en una encuentras tu problema acá, sin necesidad de preguntarle a nadie.

Comment: Que menso, ya se porque me regresaba que no existía, la comparación comenzaba a partir del 1, y como estaba comparando los valores del arreglo en 0, nunca lo encontraba.